# jQuery Using .blur() on an Image

Tags: jquery, image, radio-button

Consider an image with an ID fading in when the parent div is clicked, simple right?

I am using this technique to simulate radio buttons.

HTML

```
<div id="parent_div">
    <img id="image_id" style="display:none;" src="/images/some_image.png">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#parent_div').on('click', function(){
    $('#image_id').fadeIn(200);
});
```

Now the problem is, in Firefox (maybe other browsers as well), that when the parent div is clicked, and the image fades in, the image has the appearance of being highlighted.

With that being said, if I click somewhere else on the screen, the image highlight disappears. Is there a way to get around this without having to click elsewhere?

I tried using .blur() like so, hoping it might work.

```
$('#image_id').fadeIn(200).blur();
```

Here is a visual example: http://www.videsignz.com/images/blur_image.jpg

JSFiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/VRfuJ/

This is my fiddle view: http://www.videsignz.com/images/myfiddleview.jpg

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? This can probably be solved with just CSS...

Comment: Can blur be used on an image element ??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "highlighted", did you try `outline:none` in your css, or are you using some css framework, like jQuery mobile, bootstrap etc ?

Comment: Sushanth, I am not sure, I was just hoping it would...

Comment: Look at the link Adeneo, it shows the highlight...its as if you dragged the mouse over it as you would with text to copy and such

Comment: The image is blue with four icons? How the frack are we supposed to know how you would like it to look ?

Comment: The image on the left with the x above it is how it should not look, but does.  The one on the right it how it should look, hence the green check mark.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you're after:

```
$('img, .radio_btn').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    document.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
    e.target.ondragstart = function() { return false; };
    return false;
});

$('.radio_btn').on('click', function() {
    if (!$('img', this).is(':visible')) {
        $('img', this).fadeIn(200);
        $('.radio_btn').not(this).find('img').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VRfuJ/6/)

Comment: Thank you Adeneo, if you check the link up top to my fiddle view, that is what I am seeing when I click the radio button, even using your fiddle. It only happens the first time I might add.  Though on my page it happens each time. When I click elsewhere on the screen it goes away. Perhaps a .focus() elsewhere or a simulated click after the initial radio button selection?

Comment: Perfect Bro! I take it the deselecting of the image is happening  on the 'mousedown' solely?

Comment: At minimum, this seems to work based off Adeneos code...

$('.radio_btn').on('mousedown', function() {
    return false;
});

Comment: Yes, the mousedown function will prevent the elements in the selector, which of course are all images and any element with the class radio_btn, but could be narrowed down if needed with a more specific selector, from being selected. The last return false is'nt always needed, and it could cause issues with some slideshows etc. but in this case, it does seem like the return false is doing the job, and it would probably work with that alone. The others are for IE etc. and I just always use this snippet for custom checkboxes etc.

Comment: @adeneo please add working links in Fiddle example thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the img to a div with a background image:

Html code:

```
<div id="parent_div">
  <div id="image_id"></div>
</div>

<style>
  #parent_div {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      min-height: 20px;
    }

  #image_id {
      display:none;
      background-image: url('http://www.myfico.com/Images/sample_overlay.gif');
      width: 382px;
      height: 259px;
  }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#parent_div').on('click', function(){
    $('#image_id').fadeIn(200);
  });
</script>
```

See the (updated) plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8Hi2OP?p=preview

Good luck!

**Update**: the div is now fixed (it must be closed), see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VRfuJ/1/

Comment: Posted another possible solution, although I have to say that your fiddle seems to work for me... which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: I have went that route, and it does work, though if images are disabled I can not set an alt tag. Thank you again!

Comment: When I use the fiddle, it shows up the first time I click, then goes away after that.  Its messing with me...

Comment: The _alt_ attribute can be replaced with _title_ in _div_, e.g. `<div title="I am a div title" />`.

Comment: As far as the mess, you need to close the div. The fiddle is now updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/VRfuJ/1/

Comment: I see...though the title doesn't show up like an alt tag does with images disabled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18944/discussion-between-david-riccitelli-and-videsignz)